# How to redirect to a specific layout page according to user type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a login page that currently redirects to a default layout page when a user successfully logs in. However, I have created a different layout page for the different user and what I want to do is to be able to look through my database and check the type of user and when their username and password is correct, `response.redirect` them to a specific layout page depending on what type of user they are.  I have different views for each user type.

[The different user views under shared folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZfE1.png)

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=CHRIS\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FPSDD;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
    }

    protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PersonType FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' and PersonType='" + userType.SelectedValue + "'";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(ds, "Person");
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (userType.SelectedValue == "Student")
            {
                Response.Redirect(Url.Action(""));
            }
            else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Instructor")
            {
                Response.Redirect("");
            }
            else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Counselor")
            {
                Response.Redirect("");
            }
            else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Parent")
            {
                Response.Redirect("");
            }
            else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Principal")
            {
                Response.Redirect("");
            }
            else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Admin")
            {
                Response.Redirect("");
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PersonType FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(ds, "Person");

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type. Please Try Again!";
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type, Username or Password. Please Try Again!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read up on SQL injection

Comment: what error are you getting or any unexpected behavior?

Comment: Just modify the `/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`, based on user type you specify the `Layout = "Path\to\usertype\layout"`

Comment: @AkashKC I am not sure what to put exactly for the response.Redirect. in the code, what I want to happen is for it to look up the database and see if username, password and usertype all match in the database and if it does, see if the user type is student then redirect it to the student view, if the user type is instructor, redirect it to instructor view, and so on.

Comment: what pages do you want tor redirect? like if usertype is student, what page do you want to display?

Comment: I want it to redirect to a student view. If its an instructor, I want it to redirect to an instructor view. Currently, for all the users, its only redirecting to one specific layout mentioned in the _ViewStart.chstml

Answer (score 1):

I will expand on MCoder's original answer.

If you utilize:

```
return RedirectToAction("YourMethodName", "YourControllerName");
```

You can pass an overload of this Redirect method a parameter.

When your user logs in, return his/her user type.
Pass it into the Redirect like so:

```
return RedirectToAction("YourMethodName", "YourControllerName", new { paramName = userType });
```

And in YourController.YourMethod(paramType paramName) have a conditional statement.

```
if(paramName = x)
{
    return View("CorrectViewName", appropriateViewModel); 
}
else ...
```

If you have more than 2 or 3 user types, you can use Switch/Case instead of If/Else.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a MVC web application.
Do not use `response.redirect()`

instead use

```
return RedirectToAction("YourMethodName", "YourControllerName");
```